# UpdatePanel with GridView with LinkButton with Image Causes Full Postback

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

So this might be a fairly specific issue but I figured I'd post it since I spent hours struggling with it before I was able to determine the cause.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAttachments" DataKeyNames="UploadedID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvAttachments_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>There are no attachments associated to this email template.</EmptyDataTemplate>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Select" runat="server"><img src="/images/icons/trashcan.png" style="border: none;" /></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In the ItemTemplate of the TemplateField of the GridView I have a LinkButton with an image inside of it. Normally I do this when I have an image with some text next to it but this time, for whatever reason, I just have the image. This causes the UpdatePanel to always do a full postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the markup, you can goto web.config and specify ClientIDMode="Auto" in the pages tag.

Reason why UpdatePanel behaving like this is because the ClientIDMode is getting generated will be too long for UpdatePanel to register. So the ClientID got truncated in middle and such control will be treated like unregistered Control.

For more information read the following:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Change the LinkButton to be an ImageButton and the problem is solved.

```
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="/images/icons/trashcan.png" Style="border: none;" CommandName="Select" runat="server" />
```

Comment: what's the difference between ImageButton and LinkButton in this case? =]

Comment: There's no difference, it's just a habit I got into to use LinkButtons with an image inside. Just wanted to post this in case anyone was doing the same thing I was.

Answer (score 1):

Above solutions also work, But There is one more thing to check. Check form tag for your page. If id attribute is missing, you will get same issue.

If you form tag is as given below (without id), you will get issue:

```
<form runat="server">
    <!-- your page markup -->
</form>
```

Please add id, as given below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <!-- your page markup -->
</form>
```

You will not need to update ClientIDMode in web.config or page or control.
You will not need to change your linkbutton in markup.
You will not need to register control for asynch postback from code behind.